# Android Source build in eclipse failed - Account cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-source

I want to build the Android Source in eclipse as described here: 
http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html

I did everthing as described there but I get the error shown in this image:
[image]

In console "make" did work perferctly.

Comment: There is awfull lot of files missing. See the packages u imported in ur CalenderPickerDialogue activity.. I would advice to make a color.xml in values folder and then define color in it and with help of that resource use it in java files. It would be more convenient. Solve these errors and let me know the status in comment for further help

Comment: Also, the package name that i can see in project view is "android" and not com.android.* try removing the com.. Also see eclipse suggestions on it by hovering ur mouse pointer over ther error

Comment: The source files are original from the android repository. I dont think that I have to change anything for a successfull build... except something in the build order

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you cannot build AOSP using Eclipse. The only thing you can do is to develop parts of AOSP using Eclipse.

To use Eclipse for the development you need at first download and build AOSP from the command line, following the instructions [here](http://source.android.com/source/building.html). only after the successful built you can start to use Eclipse for the development (the build system during the build generates some files, which may be missing without the build). After that following the instructions on the link you provided, you can install Eclipse as a development system for AOSP.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Using Eclipse to browse and edit AOSP](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/using-eclipse-to-browse-and-edit-aosp.html). As mentioned above, it is not possible to build from eclipse. Plus doing so could break your AOSP build as well. Use eclipse as described in that link, but use terminal to build your changes using lunch, m, mm, mmm commands.